# Why is this PageRank job so much slower using Dataset than RDD?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I implemented [this example](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaPageRank.java) of PageRank in Java using the newer Dataset API. When I benchmark my code against the sample which uses the older RDD API, I find that my code takes 186 seconds while the baseline only takes 109 seconds. What is causing the discrepancy? (Side-note: is it normal for Spark to take hundreds of seconds even when the database only contains a handful of entries?)

My code:

```
Dataset<Row> outLinks = spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "storagepage_outlinks", props);
Dataset<Row> page = spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "pages", props);

outLinks = page.join(outLinks, page.col("id").equalTo(outLinks.col("storagepage_id")));
outLinks = outLinks.distinct().groupBy(outLinks.col("url")).agg(collect_set("outlinks")).cache();

Dataset<Row> ranks = outLinks.map(row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getString(0), 1.0), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.DOUBLE())).toDF("url", "rank");

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    Dataset<Row> joined = outLinks.join(ranks, new Set.Set1<>("url").toSeq());
    Dataset<Row> contribs = joined.flatMap(row -> {
        List<String> links = row.getList(1);
        double rank = row.getDouble(2);
        return links
                .stream()
                .map(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, rank / links.size()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).iterator();
    }, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.DOUBLE())).toDF("url", "num");

    Dataset<Tuple2<String, Double>> reducedByKey =
            contribs.groupByKey(r -> r.getString(0), Encoders.STRING())
            .mapGroups((s, iterator) -> {
                double sum = 0;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    sum += iterator.next().getDouble(1);
                }
                return new Tuple2<>(s, sum);
            }, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.DOUBLE()));
    ranks = reducedByKey.map(t -> new Tuple2<>(t._1, .15 + t._2 * .85),
            Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.DOUBLE())).toDF("url", "rank");
}
ranks.show();
```

The sample code which uses RDD (adapted to read from my database):

```
Dataset<Row> outLinks = spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "storagepage_outlinks", props);
Dataset<Row> page = spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "pages", props);

outLinks = page.join(outLinks, page.col("id").equalTo(outLinks.col("storagepage_id")));
outLinks = outLinks.distinct().groupBy(outLinks.col("url")).agg(collect_set("outlinks")).cache(); // TODO: play with this cache
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> links = outLinks.javaRDD().mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getString(0), row.getList(1)));

// Loads all URLs with other URL(s) link to from input file and initialize ranks of them to one.
JavaPairRDD<String, Double> ranks = links.mapValues(rs -> 1.0);

// Calculates and updates URL ranks continuously using PageRank algorithm.
for (int current = 0; current < 20; current++) {
    // Calculates URL contributions to the rank of other URLs.
    JavaPairRDD<String, Double> contribs = links.join(ranks).values()
            .flatMapToPair(s -> {
                int urlCount = size(s._1());
                List<Tuple2<String, Double>> results = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String n : s._1) {
                    results.add(new Tuple2<>(n, s._2() / urlCount));
                }
                return results.iterator();
            });

    // Re-calculates URL ranks based on neighbor contributions.
    ranks = contribs.reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y).mapValues(sum -> 0.15 + sum * 0.85);
}

// Collects all URL ranks and dump them to console.
List<Tuple2<String, Double>> output = ranks.collect();
for (Tuple2<?,?> tuple : output) {
    System.out.println(tuple._1() + " has rank: " + tuple._2() + ".");
}
```

Comment: Dataset is known to have slower performance. Have you tried using DataFrame instead?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** It is probably good old [Avoid GroupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) thing.

Hard to say for sure but your `Dataset` code is equivalent to `groupByKey`:

```
groupByKey(...).mapGroups(...)
```

it means that it shuffles first, then reduces the data.

Your RDD uses `reduceByKey` - this should reduce shuffle size by applying local reduction. If you want this code to be somewhat equivalent you should rewrite `groupByKey(...).mapGroups(...)` with `groupByKey(...).reduceGroups(...)`.

Another possible candidate is configuration. Default value for `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is 200 which will be used for `Dataset` aggregations. If

> the database only contains a handful of entries?

this is a serious overkill.

RDD will use `spark.default.parallelism` or value based on the parent data, which are typically much more modest.